# Compare Variable with multiple values in single If condition

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to compare variable with multiple values with "OR" condition I batch script rather having multiple if logic.

```
@echo off

robocopy D:\SourceData E:\DestinationData

If %ErrorLevel% Equ 0 OR 1 OR 2 ( GoTo Success) Else ( GoTo Error)

:Success

Echo Robocopy completed successfully.
Pause
GoTo End

:Error

Echo Robo completed with some error/s.
Paude

:End
Exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the error level with a certain list:

```
for %%a in (1 2 3 whatever) do (
  if %errorlevel% equ %%a (
     goto :Success
  )
)
goto :error
```

Answer (score 1):

ERRORLEVEL is rarely < 0, so you could use:

```
if %errorlevel% LEQ 2 ( GoTo Success) Else ( GoTo Error)
```

...and for safety just in case:

```
if %errorlevel% LEQ -1 ( GoTo Error)
```

If your values were not consecutive you could just duplicate the if lines without the else (not very good but would work)

If you know all the possible values you can just do

```
goto branch%ERRORLEVEL%
```

and define

```
:branch0
:branch1
:branch2
```

...and so on.

(this is more or less directly lifted from `IF` online help, I learned a lot with the /? switch of commands like that)

Comment: just to note: `errorlevel` **can** be negative. (although most programs don't use it, but there are some, that do)